# Android - how to change the background color of the selected item in a dropdown

Tags: android

I have the following dropdown:

```
<style name="SpinnerDropdown" parent="android:style/Widget.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:background">#04384f</item>
    <item name="android:divider">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>  
</style>
```

[image: Problem]

I want to change the color of the currently pressed item. This color is currently orange (#feba21) and I want it to be something else. I haven't set it anywhere so I assume it's inherited from Widget.ListView.Dropdown

How can I change it, and more importantly where can I find Windget.ListView.Dropdown in the SDK so I can see what properties it has?

I tried adding the selector_spinner_option:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/bright_positive" />  
    <item android:drawable="@color/dimmer_positive" />
</selector>
```

as the background of SpinnerDropdown, but what it does is change all the other items when one item is pressed - while that item remains orange!!

Comment: try using selector  will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orange is not the background of dropdown item. It is a color of selector. It is easy to change it by the attribute `listSelector`

The following code will change orange to green

```
<style name="SpinnerDropdown" parent="android:style/Widget.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:background">#04384f</item>
    <item name="android:divider">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">#00ff00</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>  
</style>
```

Hope it help.

Comment: When I open the dropdown, the app crashes and says res/color/btn_bg.xml not found even though there is a file with that name in that folder.

Comment: Maybe you need to clean project and rebuild.

Comment: I just did, still crashes. android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/btn_bg.xml from drawable resource ID

Comment: I have test it, same issue, maybe it don't support color state list, drawable selector is ok.

Comment: Still doesn't work, I've updated my question with that. The entire dropdown changes to #FF50C1AB but the pressed item remains orange.

Comment: Drawable selector is work but not good for your situation. I have update my answer.

Comment: So it's not possible to change the style of single items in a listview dropdown?

Comment: It is possble. I get it finally. The dropdown item is not the background of item, It is a color of selector. I have updated my answer please check it.

Comment: That's it! Thanks for your help. In the end it was so simple and the only place I didn't try setting the listSelector

Comment: Does someone know how to do this programatically, like listview.setSelector()?